# jQuery Tooltip remains open if it's on a link within an iframe (in FF & IE)

Tags: jquery-ui, iframe, fancybox-2, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm replacing the standard "Reset your password" text link with a help' icon, but I discovered that when a jQuery Tooltip is on a link within an iframe, it remains open once the link is clicked until the parent page is refreshed.

I'm using inline frames, but I also experienced the same problem when linking to another page. I tried moving the title inside a `<span>` tag, as well as closing the iframe and opening a new one with the functions below, but the tooltip just remains open on the page.

**UPDATE** - I created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/7k77j/2/ *(Click on 'Reset Link')*.  I experience the problem in both Firefox & IE (it's fine in Chrome & Safari).

*HTML*

```
<a href="#inline_form" class="fancybox_inline" title="Forgot Your Password?"><img src="help.jpg"></a>
```

*Functions to close iframe and open new iframe*

```
function close_iframe() {
    parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
     }

function open_iframe() {
    $.fancybox.open([{href:'reset_password.html'}], { type:'iframe'           
         });
     }
```

I am using jquery-1.8.2, jquery-ui-1.9.1 and fancyapps2

Comment: Can you add a demo of this problem, perhaps on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or add more of the HTML and jQuery to the question? It's difficult to produce a test case without it :-)

Comment: @andyb - I took your advice and created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/7k77j/2/ Click on 'Reset Link'

Comment: Tooltip fades out fine here. Chrome 25; what browser are you using?

Comment: @Mooseman - You're absolutely right :-) I find that most things work in Firefox so that's usually my starting point. I just tested it and it's fine in Chrome & Safari, but I experienced the problem in Firefox & IE. I'll update the question to include that info now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be an incompatibility or bug between the fancybox and the jQueryUI tooltip.

Essentially, the fancybox is showing the second form but the browser is not seeing the [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/mouseout) event. You can check this by adding a callback function to the [`.close()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-close) event of the jQueryUI tooltip.

```
$('a[href="#inline_form1"]').tooltip({
    close: function( event, ui ) {
      console.log('closing')
    }
})
```

You should be able to see `closing` in the console in IE, Firefox and Chrome when the mouse moves out of the "Reset Link" anchor. However, when clicking "Reset Link" in Chrome you see the `closing` log line again but in IE9 it does not appear again. So the browser is missing the event.

We can work around this by manually calling `.tooltip('close')` when "Reset Link" is clicked, like this:

```
$('a[href="#inline_form1"]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).tooltip('close')
})
```

There is a small problem with the way in which the tooltips are created which means that with just the above *click handler* it will error with

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

This seems to be caused by using the `$(document).tooltip()` method which uses event delegation for all elements with a title attribute. This is the simplest way of creating tooltips for all elements so I understand why this is used but it can add unnecessary events and handling to the whole page rather than targeting specific elements. So looking at the error it is telling us that we need to explicitly create a tooltip on the element we want to call `'close'` on. So need to add the following initialisation

```
$('a[href="#inline_form1"]').tooltip();
```

Sp here is the completed JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      title: ''
    })

    $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click')

    $(document).tooltip();
    $('a[href="#inline_form1"]').tooltip()

     $('a[href="#inline_form1"]').on('click', function() {
       $(this).tooltip('close')
    })
})
```

**Note:** You only need one jQuery [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) wrapping function - the `$(function (){ ... })` part :-)

Comment: That works perfectly, and it's an even more perfect answer :-D Out of curiosity, can I use one jQuery document.ready wrapping function for all of my functions, or am I better off grouping the related functions together?

Comment: You can have one or many [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) functions, it makes no difference to jQuery. However it does [impact performance](http://jsperf.com/docready/11), so it's best to use one if possible. Each project is different but for large projects the generally practised approach is to keep your JS, CSS, HTML in modules and use a preprocessor to concatenate the CSS into a single file - see the Chrome DevTools Network tab for stackoverflow - 1 CSS file :-) Same goes for the site's JS. For small projects it's not so important but the fewer HTTP requests the better.

Comment: I've been having performance issues so I've been trying to sort that out :-) I wasn't sure if it would slow things down if there was a lot of code that wasn't relevant for a given document, and/or if there was a benefit to keeping JS & CSS in the document if it was only being used in one document.

Comment: However you do it, putting JS and CSS in separate files will allow the browser to cache them which reduces return visit page load times. Although arguably this also needs correct configuration of the web server as well. General page performance could be down to many other factors like the browser, how many events are firing, CSS transition/animations, JS animations, etc&hellip; Chrome DevTools has a Timeline tab which might be able to help highlight bottlenecks :-)

Comment: That's super helpful :-D I've also had a strange problem with it sometimes not recognizing some of the JS or CSS when it's in a separate document (even though it's working fine for everything else in that document) - Any chance that you'd know why that happens or if there's a tool that could help me figure out the cause?

Comment: Sounds like the browser might have an old copy of the file in the cache which is the side effect of caching. Could be an issue with the web server not indicating that the file has changed. You can always *force* a browser to download a fresh copy. In Chrome with the DevTools open, you can right click on the reload to get some hidden options about forcing reloads. Otherwise, it might be that a path to a resource in your CSS or JS is relative and the way in which the CSS or JS is included means that the path is incorrect.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this :-D It can be quite difficult to try to piece together some of this information, and this will be a huge help :-D

Comment: I mostly use `data-toggle="tooltip"` everywhere where I want tooltips instead of plain `title="My title text here"` and then register on it in one common place with (within `ready()` event!) something like: `$( "[data-toggle=tooltip]" ).tooltip();`. I have updated the fiddle a bit.

Comment: You also want to register your `click()` events on ids not href or so. Example: `<a id="link-forgot-password" ...>Forgot password?</a>` and: `$('#link-forgot-password').click(function() { doSomething; });`. This both is both performing better and gives you lesser maintenance when you rewrite things.